# VB Event cannot be called directly, use raiseevent

Tags: vb.net, events

Apparently I can't call an event directly in VB and I need to use the raise event statement to initiate that event. I don't know what the `RaiseEvent` statement is or how to use it and the Microsoft support site is vague and useless. Can someone please help me re-work this section.

This is my VB conversion:

```
        Public Sub ttApiInitComplete(api As TTAPI, ex As ApiCreationException)
        If ex Is Nothing Then
            ' Connect to X_TRADER
            apiInstance = DirectCast(api, XTraderModeTTAPI)
            apiInstance.ConnectionStatusUpdate += New EventHandler(Of ConnectionStatusUpdateEventArgs)(AddressOf m_apiInstance_ConnectionStatusUpdate)
            apiInstance.Start()

            Console.WriteLine("API Initialization Complete")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("API Initialization Failed - see ex.Message for details")
        End If
    End Sub
```

This is to original working C#

```
        public void ttApiInitComplete(TTAPI api, ApiCreationException ex)
    {
        if (ex == null)
        {
            // Connect to X_TRADER
            apiInstance = (XTraderModeTTAPI)api;
            apiInstance.ConnectionStatusUpdate += new EventHandler<ConnectionStatusUpdateEventArgs>(m_apiInstance_ConnectionStatusUpdate);
            apiInstance.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("API Initialization Complete");

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("API Initialization Failed - see ex.Message for details");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is the translator.  Use `AddHandler` to add a handler instead of `+=`

Comment: I think the premise of the question isn't really clear. The original code is only adding an event handler, not calling (or raising) it directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB.NET has an `AddHandler` method that works similarly to the way the '+' overload operator works for adding event handlers in C#. There's no '+' used that way in VB. You specify the event you want to capture and the handler to fire when it occurs:

You'd call it roughly like so:

```
AddHandler apiInstance.ConnectionStatusUpdate, AddressOf Me.YourEventHandler
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to custom events

AddHandler and RaiseEvent

Add handler tells the code which function to run when a particular event fires.

```
AddHandler apiInstance.INitComplete, AddressOf Me.ttApiInitComplete
```

To create custom events in your class of whatever declare

```
Public Event YourEventName(.. enter your arguments here...)
```

Then when you need to raise it...

```
RaiseEvent YourEventName(... Your ARguments...)
```

As an alternative to AddHandler you can also use

```
Private WithEvents YourClassrObjectName as WhateverItIS
```

Then that object will appear in the intellisense list of objects with events listed.

Something like this...

```
Private WithEvents myApi as TTAPI
Public Sub ttApiInitComplete(sender As TTAPI, ex As ApiCreationException) handles myApi.InitComplete
    If ex Is Nothing Then
        ' Connect to X_TRADER
        apiInstance = DirectCast(api, XTraderModeTTAPI)
        apiInstance.ConnectionStatusUpdate += New EventHandler(Of ConnectionStatusUpdateEventArgs)(AddressOf m_apiInstance_ConnectionStatusUpdate)
        apiInstance.Start()

        Console.WriteLine("API Initialization Complete")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("API Initialization Failed - see ex.Message for details")
    End If
End Sub
```